# network setup when installing ubuntu core on raspberry pi 3

Tags: networking, ubuntu

Does anyone know what I need to do with network configuration when installing Ubuntu core on the Raspberry Pi 3?

I was able to download the Ubuntu image and copy it onto a small SD card as the Ubuntu page describes, but when I try to use it to install Ubuntu on my Raspberry Pi 3, I get stuck on the initial network configuration menu.  I can't figure out what it wants me to set there.

I tried entering the same info I got from my other laptop using `ipconfig` with the static address options, but that didn't work. I then tried using the other option that starts with a D and just says uses ....  I tried just leaving it set to Don't Use, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [here's a video](https://youtu.be/Gxg2r-BmvrQ) taking you through the steps of installing Ubuntu Core on a Raspberry Pi 3. Basically, from what you are saying, you are stuck at configuring what us old timers would call the `/etc/interfaces`. Here's a few bits of information to help you figure out what you need to put in here:

- eth0 is your ethernet cable interface. Make sure you have a network cable plugged in that goes to a router if you are intending on using this
- wlan0 is your WiFi interface. Make sure you have the WiFi's name and password if you are intending on using this
- static address means you want your Raspberry Pi to always be at that IP address. This is usually preferable, but it's not a have-to
- DHCP is the opposite of a static address. Your router will be assigning your Pi an IP address. This is easier to setup and can usually be changed later
- IPv4 or DHCPV4 is the "old-school" IP address system. This is what most people use
- IPV6 or DHCPV6 is the "new and improved" IP address system. You probably don't need this